# How can I show a dropdown in my form with the title of the objects in the table? Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hi I've been trying to create a simple app for workflows or binary protocols (yes or no instructions, very helpful sometimes)
[image: here is how the form dropdown looks like]

I have created a simple form with ModelForm:

```
class BlocForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model  = Bloc
    fields = [
        'description',
        'loop_child'
        ]
```

and my model looks like this:

```
class Loopeable(models.Model):
     protocol    = models.ForeignKey(Protocol, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
     description = models.TextField()
     pointing_at = models.IntegerField()

class Bloc(models.Model):
     description = models.TextField()
     protocol    = models.ForeignKey(Protocol, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     parent      = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
     loop_child  = models.ForeignKey(Loopeable, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
     question    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     end_bloc    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And my problem is that instead of having this loop_chile dropdown list of ugly objects I would like to get the description in the Loopeable Model, is there a way to get some data that is not just "Loopeable Object (id_number)". I didn't add my views.py in order to keep the post short, but I implemented the for by simply doing something like:

```
form = BlocForm(request.POST or None)
      if form.is_valid(): ...rest of the code
```

If anyone has some ideas I will be grateful!! Thanks...

Comment: You need to add a `__str__` method to your `Loopeable` class

Comment: thanks, it worked like a charm... I am new to django so I dont know how to do all this things that are basic... although it surprised me that I couldn't find any post about it.